# Organizing a React JS project - building single JS file

Tags: reactjs, browserify

I just got started using React. I went through the CommentBox tutorial without any issues. But the framework does not give much/any guidance to organizing your JS files or compiling a single minified JS file for a SPA. I already know the framework is flexible and does not enforce a standard and I'm sure these questions are probably dead obvious for someone who develops in the Javascript ecosystem.

I would imagine the consensus is to use Browserify and in the docs there's a link to a git starter project:

https://github.com/petehunt/react-browserify-template

This is a good start, but still it only compiles a single JS file "index.js". I read through some of the browserify handbook and I thought I simply had to 'require' my other files (and those files need to export themselves).

So I modified index.js to look like this:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var pkg = require('./package.json');

var commentBox = require('./comment-box.js');
```

comment-box.js is basically a hello world test:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="commentBox">
            Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
            </div>
            );
    }
});

React.renderComponent(
    <CommentBox />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);

module.exports = CommentBox;
```

If I run the react-browserify-template's start target it seems to generate browser-bundle.js fine:

```
npm start
```

But if I try the build target

```
npm build
```

...nothing happens. I changed the output of npm to verbose and I get the following:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'build' ]
npm info using npm@1.4.21
npm info using node@v0.10.24
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
```

According to package.json it's supposed to generate a file "browser-bundle.min.js" but instead I get no output.  I'm hoping someone can clear this up.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at my template here (React + browserify + gulp): https://gist.github.com/fkling/e34147a800b085a17563

Comment: I might have spoke too fast. It seems to be failing for nested components. Will update question.

Comment: You have to require `CommentList.js` inside `CommentBox.js`. Every module takes care of its own dependencies. Also it should be `require('React')`, not `require('react')`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that.  I was just about to update it :) It worked.

Comment: Perhaps one of you should consider making the solution into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. As I stated originally, it is probably obvious for someone who's been developing in the JS ecosystem :)

The package.json in the [react-browserify-template](https://github.com/petehunt/react-browserify-template/blob/master/package.json) has three scripts in the "scripts" section with the keys "start", "build", and "test".

As I said previously, start worked fine by running:

```
npm start
```

I wrongly assumbed that I could run the build script similarly:

```
npm build (this will never work and there will be no errors/output)
```

It turns out I needed to run the build script using:

```
npm run-script build
```

One extra line in the documentation might have saved me hours of trouble :D  I'm now using this approach as it seems quite a bit simpler.  Also, it sets NODE_ENV to production and uses envify which apparently is important: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1772

One other thing, some of the official examples such as [todomvc-flux](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/examples/todomvc-flux/js/app.js) use the lowercase 'react' in the require function:

```
var React = require('react');
```

so I suppose that's the recommended syntax (?)

Comment: FWIW, there is a file at the root of the project called `USAGE.txt` that explains that you should run `npm run build` to get the minified version.

Comment: Yes you're right. I did see that some time ago (well after I had posted this comment). I should have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: As for the lowercase `require('react')`, it shouldn't work otherwise. The package is called `react` not `React` (to computers there's a difference).  All package names are lowercase now, FYI

Answer (score 0):

Working solution using Felix's gist. Note: This is not 100% equivalent to the react-browserify-template which uses envify and the production flag to get rid of some React debugging (mainly "Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: http://fb.me/react-devtools" which is printed to the console on startup).

Perhaps a mod can give Felix credit for the solution?

App.js

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */
"use strict";

var React = require('React');

var CommentBox = require('./components/CommentBox.js');

React.renderComponent(
    <CommentBox />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

components/CommentBox.js

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('React');
var CommentList = require('./CommentList.js');

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="commentBox">
                <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList />
            </div>
            );
    }
});

module.exports = CommentBox;
```

components/CommentList.js

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('React');
var CommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="commentList">
            Hello, world! I am a CommentList.
            </div>
            );
    }
});

module.exports = CommentList;
```